# Using Jquery to capture click event of <asp:FileUpload> control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

My code:

```
<script>
    $('.Upload').on("click", function () {
        alert("Click event found using class as identifier");
    });

    $('#FileUpload1').on("click", function () {
        alert("Click event found using ID as identifier");
    });
</script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="Upload" />
```

I'm using the latest version of Jquery(1.9) which is why I'm using `.on` instead of `.live`

But neither of my alerts fire when I click the 'browse' button.

Can anyone help at all ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You must use delegation with .on() synthax, see equivalent to live():

```
$(document).on("click",".Upload",function(){...});
```